# Adding Sharepoint document version in word 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, word

I'm trying to include the Sharepoint document version in a word document Microsoft 365 environment. I can't find the version tag in Word quick part. I can see the document version history in Sharepoint but I'm not able to pick up the version of the document in word. How do I enable the usage of the version tag in Word 365?

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, if you use the Microsoft 365, you shall be able to view the version history directly through the [word approach](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-previous-versions-of-office-files-5c1e076f-a9c9-41b8-8ace-f77b9642e2c2). Click **File** > **Info** > **Version history** shall be enough.

Comment: I would like to have a quick part in the header of the document that shows the version of the document. Very useful if the document is printed.

Comment: @Claes, that shall be doable to add a version label. Here is an example:https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d7edacd9-3818-4b66-982a-daa1846fbe2a/add-the-sharepoint-version-number-to-a-word-document?forum=onlineservicessharepoint